# Read the data of a single channel from a stereo wave file in Python

Tags: python, scipy, wave

I have to read the data from just one channel in a stereo wave file in Python.
For this I tried it with scipy.io:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wf
import numpy

def read(path):
    data = wf.read(path)
    for frame in data[1]:
        data = numpy.append(data, frame[0])
    return data
```

But this code is very slow, especially if I have to work with longer files.
So does anybody know a faster way to do this? I thought about the standard *wave* module by using *wave.readframes()*, but how are the frames stored there?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) returns the tuple `(rate, data)`.  If the file is stereo, `data` is a numpy array with shape `(nsamples, 2)`.  To get a specific channel, use a [slice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) of `data`.  For example,

```
rate, data = wavfile.read(path)
# data0 is the data from channel 0.
data0 = data[:, 0]
```

Comment: In a stereo file, "channel" refers to either the left or right signal.  That is, `left = data[:, 0]`, `right = data[:, 1]`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995936/what-is-a-channel-in-a-wav-file-formatdo-all-channels-play-simultaneaously-whe

Comment: this works great, however how do i pass this channel without saving as wav to another function?

Comment: That depends on the format of the input expected by the other function.  You should create a new stackoverflow question for this.  The comments are not the place to solve new problems.

Comment: thx u sir, i created a question - could u pls look into it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467345/how-to-pass-edited-wav-between-functions-without-saving-wav-in-between

Answer (score 7):

The `wave` module returns the frames as a string of bytes, which can be converted to numbers with the `struct` module. For instance:

```
def oneChannel(fname, chanIdx):
""" list with specified channel's data from multichannel wave with 16-bit data """
    f = wave.open(fname, 'rb')
    chans = f.getnchannels()
    samps = f.getnframes()
    sampwidth = f.getsampwidth()
    assert sampwidth == 2
    s = f.readframes(samps) #read the all the samples from the file into a byte string
    f.close()
    unpstr = '<{0}h'.format(samps*chans) #little-endian 16-bit samples
    x = list(struct.unpack(unpstr, s)) #convert the byte string into a list of ints
    return x[chanIdx::chans] #return the desired channel
```

If your WAV file has some other sample size, you can use the (uglier) function in another answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999599/120261).

I've never used `scipy`'s `wavfile` function so I can't compare speed, but the `wave` and `struct` approach I use here has always worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

rate, audio = wavfile.read(path)

audio = np.mean(audio, axis=1)

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer and format it properly? The question already has an accepted answer.

Comment: @Elijah: Please read community guidelines on writing good answer: `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer`